# PHP script reports wrong credentials

Tags: php, mysql

Ok, this is my code for authentication. For now, i have one table and 5 PHP working scripts except this one. After successful login, user should be redirected to his home page, but the problem is, PHP echoes "Cannot login" error message regardless of login details. Heres the script:

```
session_start();
include_once'dbconnect.php';
    if (isset($_SESSION['user']) != "") {
        header ("Location: home.php");  
    }

    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".$email."'");
        $num = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);

            if ($num['password'] == $pass)) {
                $_SESSION['user'] = $num['user_id'];
                header ("Location: home.php");
            }
                else {
                    echo "Cannot login";
                }
    }
```

Any hints ? Thank you

Comment: try to add a `var_dump($num);` before the last `if` and show us the result please

Comment: You're comparing an escaped password with the value retrieved from the database which _won't_ be escaped. You should only escape data immediately prior to storing it in the database and In any case, you __shouldn't__ store passwords in plain text.

Comment: Heres the result: array(4) { ["user_id"]=> string(2) "20" ["username"]=> string(4) "pkom" ["email"]=> string(22) "something@gmail.com" ["password"]=> string(4) "hzvt" }

Comment: ok, can you show us the result of this `var_dump(array($num['password'], $_POST['pass'], ($num['password'] == $_POST['pass'])));` before the last `if`, please?

Comment: array(3) { [0]=> string(4) "hzvt" [1]=> string(4) "hzvt" [2]=> bool(true) }

Comment: It's not possible that your code returns "Cannot login" and this result, no way.

Comment: wait.. change `if (isset($_SESSION['user']) != "") {`for this `if (isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user'] != "") {`

Comment: Are you encrypting your password before storing it in the database?

Comment: I only use mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass'])) when storing it to the password variable

Comment: Actually, scratch that, md5 encrypton was used, so yeah, password was encrypted. Thats the downside when multiple persons edit the same file. So now i have redirection error when logged in :S

Comment: What do you mean by redirection error? Please elaborate.

Comment: Firefox error: The page isn't redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
include_once'dbconnect.php';
    if (isset($_SESSION['user']) != "") {
        header ("Location: home.php");  
    }

    if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pass']);
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='".$email."'");
        $num = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
        if(count($num)>0){
            if ($num['password'] == $pass)) {
                $_SESSION['user'] = $num['user_id'];
                header ("Location: home.php");
            }
                else {
                    echo "Cannot login";
                }
        }else{
          echo "Cannot login, email id not found";
        }

    }
```

Make sure you are getting password from the data base.

Comment: echo $num['password']."|".$pass; insert this after count($num). Verify both passwords are same.\

Answer (score 0):

```
1.I think Your password encrypted in db.

2.Check it out it may be md5,sha etc.

3.If yes. Change Like this

 if ($num['password'] == md5($pass)){
     .
     .
     .
     .
 }
```

Hope It Helps..

Comment: Yeah, md5 was an issue. Thx for reply, but now i have problems with redirected homepage after login